# Visio Indentation of Sub-Bullet Point

Tags: visio

I have a bulleted list in Visio 2010 in which I'm trying to indent a second-level bullet. For example:

[image: Second-level bullet screenshot]

I want the "Sub-Bullet" item to be indented to the right so it's clear that it is a child element. I thought the "Increase Indent" option on the ribbon would do this but that applies at the paragraph level so the entire list moves to the right.

How do I indent just one item in the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, select that item ("Sub-Bullet") and then use "Increase indent"...

Comment: The "increase ident" only moves the bullet text, not the actual bullet as well

Comment: Please check out this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tusfaiO9W9U

Am I missing something?

Comment: ah, I see. By select, you mean "highlight". I was just placing my cursor on that line. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1- Select text area with the bullet points

2- Choose the 'paragraph' ribbon section in the HOME tab.

3- Under paragraph --> Indentation --> reduce/increase the indentation 'before text'